# ActiveRecord, Intentionally truncate string to db column width

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 4, ActiveRecord and it's MySQL adapter are set up so if you try to save an attribute in an AR model to a MySQL db, where the attribute string length is too wide for the MySQL column limits -- you'll get an exception raised.

Great! This is much better default than Rails3, where it silently truncated the string.

However, occasionally I have an attribute that I explicitly want to be simply truncated to the maximum size allowed by the db, with no exception.  I'm having trouble figuring out the best/supported way to do this with AR.

- It should ideally happen as soon as the attribute is set, but I'd take it happening on save. (This isn't exactly a 'validation', as I never want to raise, just truncate, but maybe the validation system is the best supported way to do this?)
- Ideally, it would automatically figure out the db column width through AR's db introspection, so if the db column width changed (in a later migration), the truncation limit would change accordingly. But if that's not possible, I'll take a hard-coded truncation limit.
- Ideally it would be generic AR code that would work with any db, but if there's no good way to do that I'd take code that only worked for MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could truncate your data before inserting in db with a `before_save` or a `before_validation`
See [Active Record Callbacks — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) and [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

You can retrieve informations on your table with `MODEL.columns` and `MODEL.columns_hash`.
See [ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html)

For example (not tested):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :truncate_col
  ......

  def truncate_col
    col_size = User.columns_hash['your_column'].limit
    self.your_column = self.your_column.truncate(col_size)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can accomplish this with a combination of ActiveRecord callbacks and ConnectionsAdapters.  ActiveRecord contains several [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) you can override to perform specific logic at different points during the save flow.  Since the exception is being thrown at save, I would recommend adding your logic to the `before_save` method.  Using the [column](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column) ConnectionAdapter you should be able to determine the limit of the column you wish to insert, though the logic will most likely be different for strings vs ints, etc.  Off the top of my head you'll probably want to implement something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def before_save
        limit = User.columns_hash['attribute'].limit
        self.attribute = self.attribute[0..limit-1] if self.attribute.length > limit
    end
end
```

The above example is for a string, but this solution should work for all connection adapters assuming they support the limit attribute.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to address a few points:

If the data type of `your_column` is `text`, in Rails 4 `User.columns_hash['your_column'].limit` will return `nil`. It returns a number in case of `int` or `varchar`.

The text data type in MySQL has a storage limit of 64k. Meaning truncating upon char length is not enough if the content has non ascii chars like `ç` which needs more than 1 byte to be stored.

I've bumped into this problem very recently, here is a hotfix for it:

```rb
before_save :truncate_your_column_to_fit_into_max_storage_size

def truncate_your_column_to_fit_into_max_storage_size
  return if your_column.blank?

  max_field_size_in_bytes = 65_535

  self.your_column = your_column[0, max_field_size_in_bytes]

  while your_column.bytesize > max_field_size_in_bytes
    self.your_column = your_column[0..-2]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own self-answer, which truncates on attribute set (way before save). Curious if anyone has any feedback. It seems to work!

```
# An ActiveRecord extension that will let you automatically truncate
# certain attributes to the maximum length allowed by the DB. 
#
#     require 'truncate_to_db_limit'
#     class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
#        extend TruncateToDbLimit
#        truncate_to_db_limit :short_attr, :short_attr2
#        #...
#
# Truncation is done whenever the attribute is set, NOT waiting
# until db save. 
#
# For a varchar(4), if you do:
#    model.short_attr = "123456789"
#    model.short_attr # => '1234'
#
#
# We define an override to the `attribute_name=` method, which ActiveRecord, I think,
# promises to call just about all the time when setting the attribute. We call super
# after truncating the value. 
module TruncateToDbLimit

  def truncate_to_db_limit(*attribute_names)
    attribute_names.each do |attribute_name|
      ar_attr = columns_hash[attribute_name.to_s]

      unless ar_attr
        raise ArgumentError.new("truncate_to_db_limit #{attribute_name}: No such attribute")
      end

      limit   = ar_attr.limit

      unless limit && limit.to_i != 0
        raise ArgumentError.new("truncate_to_db_limit #{attribute_name}: Limit not known")
      end

      define_method "#{attribute_name}=" do |val|
        normalized = val.slice(0, limit)
        super(normalized)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So the main problem with this solution is the class can no longer even be loaded if the AR connection is not set to a valid db, since it tries to introspect on the db on load. There's probably a way around that with lazy loading, but I'll prob just go with the before_validation solution, where I'm less worried about the expense of looking up the db limit on each call.